# Z3 return different answers WITH and WITHOUT using push/pop?

Tags: z3, smt

When checking the following problem using Z3, I receive different answers when wrapping or not wrapping it by a pair of `push/pop`

```
(declare-fun sz_53 () Int)
(declare-fun x () Int)
(declare-fun u () Int)
(declare-fun y () Int)
(assert (> u 0))
(assert (= (+ y (- 0 0)) 0))
(assert (or (= (- x u) 0) (> x 0)))
(assert (<= (* (- 0 1) sz_53) 0))
(assert (or (= (- x u) 0) (not (= (- x u) 0))))
(assert (not (and (and (and (and (exists ((sz_64 Int)) (and (= sz_64 0) (exists ((sz_62 Int)) (and (exists ((sz_55 Int)) (and (<= (* (- 0 1) sz_55) 0) (= (+ sz_53 (- sz_62 sz_55)) 0))) (= (+ sz_62 (- (- 0 1) sz_64)) 0))))) (>= y 0)) (or (= (+ x (* (- 0 1) y)) 0) (> x 0))) (not (= (+ u (* (- 0 1) y)) 0))) (not (= (+ u (* (- 0 1) y)) 0)))))
(assert (not false))
(check-sat)
```

Particularly, when checking it directly (not wrapping by `push/pop`), Z3 returns `unsat`
(Here is the online link: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/cDt3)

However, when wrapping it by `push/pop`, Z3 returns `unknown`
(http://rise4fun.com/Z3/epyh0)

Is there anybody who knows why Z3 behaves like this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

This problem contains universal quantifiers (not ... (exists ... )), and Z3 will give up on those problems when it thinks it can't solve it (that's why you get `unknown`). Depending on which strategy/tactic/solver is used, it may decide to give up earlier or later. In this particular case, it uses a solver that doesn't support push/pop, adding them causes it to fall back onto a different solver (or parameter settings) that make it give up.

There are multiple questions on StackOverflow on this and related issues, e.g., [z3 produces unknown for assertions without quantifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197344/z3-produces-unknown-for-assertions-without-quantifiers), [Different check-sat answers when asserting same property in between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29166588/different-check-sat-answers-when-asserting-same-property-in-between/29185665#29185665), [Why does Z3 return “unknown” on this simple input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670784/why-does-z3-return-unknown-on-this-simple-input)

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer! I have read related questions and answers that you mentioned but there isn't any good solution for this situation. I feel that in this case, Z3 gives up ... so soon. Hope that it will be improved in future releases.